# Rotation on canvas

Tags: javascript, rotation, html5-canvas, coordinate-transformation

I'm drawing some shapes on canvas, but rotation freaks me up. From tutorials I found cannot find solution because of my stupid head or they are not showing interactive transformation, or both.

I made the code that draws some shapes with `mousedown`-`mousemove`-`mouseup` events, but I want to rotating while `mousemove` point is on... `(x1, y1)` - starting point and `(x2, y2)` ending point. Please be free to upgrade the code below:

```
context.strokeRect(x1, y1, x2-x1, y2-y1);
```

So what exactly could I write for those rectangles to follow point `(x2, y2)` while holding the button?

Comment: like this? http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/wiki/Examples

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What do you want exactly? to rotate an already existing rectangle? To create a new rectangle and rotate it? And are the x1/y1 and x2/y2 of the strokeRect those of the mose move?

Comment: "X1" is "mousedown" and x2 = ev.layerX; mousemove point. Draw rectangle by moving clicked mouse on empty canvas is easily even for me, and while holding click and moving the mouse, as you can see in code, rectagle stretches proportionally so on mouseup it stays in shape as has been on mouseup event. But I want, while holding the mousebutton and rotating arround origin, to rectangle also rotate arround origin point (x1,y1). I try to make myself clear. I hope it's understendable, thank you for trying to help.

Comment: The rotation should occur on a second click?
Because otherwise, I don't see clearly the effect it should achieve. The point located under the mouse is always a corner of the rectangle during the mousemove no?

Comment: The rotation have to be in same function defined by some other statements, because when I release mousebutton the loop ends, and the rectangle is drawn. Ofcourse I could rotation put on "mouseup" but then it wouldn't be visible while drawing loop works, and rotation would be applied "on blind". ....and ofcourse (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) are on diagonal corners of rectangle if it does mean anything to you.

Comment: Maybe link will help to understand: http://www.atarado.com/en/stripboard-layout-editor/stripboard-layout-editor-by-atarado.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution, follow the code:

```
var xd = x2-x1,
yd = y2-y1;
var theta = Math.atan2(yd, xd); 
var deg = theta*180/Math.PI;
var xyd = Math.sqrt((xd*xd)+(yd*yd));


context.lineWidth = 1;
context.lineCap = "square";
context.strokeStyle = "#856020";
context.save();
context.translate(x1,y1);
context.rotate(theta);
context.strokeRect(0,0,xyd,yd);
context.restore();
```